# MS Access filtering issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having an issue with automatically filtering a report/form based on a combo box.

This particular line:

`Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = strAT & " AND " & strBur & " AND " & strFT`

How do I fix this syntax?

Thank You

```
Dim strBur As String
Dim strAT As String
Dim strFT As String

strBur = "Bureau='" & Me.cboBur.Value & "'"
strAT = "Categories'" & Me.cboCategories.Value & "'"
strFT = "[Funding Type]'" & Me.cboFunding.Value & "'"


If cboBur = "All Bureaus" Then
If cboCategories = "All Categories" Then
If cboFunding = "All Funding Type" Then
Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = ""
Form_sfrnSpending.FilterOn = False
End If
End If
End If


If cboBur <> "All Bureaus" Then
If cboCategories = "All Categories" Then
If cboFunding = "All Funding Type" Then
Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = strBur
 Form_sfrmSpending.FilterOn = True
End If
End If
End If

If Me.cboCategories <> "All Categories" Then
If cboBur = "All Bureaus" Then
If cboFunding = "All Funding Type" Then
Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = strAT
Form_sfrmSpending.FilterOn = True
End If
End If
End If

If Me.cboFunding <> "All Funding Type" Then
If cboBur = "All Bureaus" Then
If cboCategories = "All Categories" Then
Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = strFT
Form_sfrmSpending.FilterOn = True
End If
End If
End If

If Me.cboCategories <> "All Action Types" Then
If cboBur <> "All Bureaus" Then
If cboFunding <> "All Funding Type" Then

Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = strAT & " AND " & strBur & " AND " & strFT
Form_sfrmSpending.FilterOn = True
Debug.Print Form_sfrmSpending.Filter
End If
End If
End If
```

I added the full code for any confusion.

Comment: Can you give an example of the values held by your strings?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I added the full code

Comment: Thanks. Am also curious when this code is called. BTW, it might be good to make yourself a much simpler version and progressively add complications, as a way to figure out where things are breaking down. The simpler the case, the more likely you are to have someone be able to help you!

Comment: If your string variables contain strings, not numbers, then you have to surround them with `'`. And always please provide the error message you get! Maybe also use an `Debug.Print strAT & " AND " & strBur & " AND " & strFT` to output the condition and show it for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `=` sign in two code lines.

You have it here:

```
strBur = "Bureau='" & Me.cboBur.Value & "'"
                ^
```

but it's missing here, creating syntax errors:

```
strAT = "Categories '" & Me.cboCategories.Value & "'"
                   ^
strFT = "[Funding Type] '" & Me.cboFunding.Value & "'"
                       ^
```

---

Also, your logic is too complicated. You can build the filter string with one single `If` for each combo box:

```
Dim sFilter As String
sFilter = ""

If cboBur <> "All Bureaus" Then
    sFilter = StrAppend(sFilter, strBur, " AND ")
End If
If cboCategories <> "All Categories" Then
    sFilter = StrAppend(sFilter, strAT, " AND ")
End If
' etc.

If sFilter <> "" Then
    Form_sfrmSpending.Filter = sFilter
    Form_sfrmSpending.FilterOn = True
End If
```

using this helper function that includes the Separator only if both strings aren't empty:

```
Public Function StrAppend(sBase As String, sAppend As Variant, sSeparator As String) As String

    If Len(sAppend) > 0 Then
        If sBase = "" Then
            StrAppend = Nz(sAppend, "")
        Else
            StrAppend = sBase & sSeparator & Nz(sAppend, "")
        End If
    Else
        StrAppend = sBase
    End If

End Function
```